# Drag & drop path info into front end?

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x, files-and-directories

On OSX at least, it's possible to quickly retrieve a folder/file path by dragging & dropping the folder/file into the terminal, eg:

[image]

Is it possible to program *Mathematica*'s front end enable similar drag & drop operation? I'm primarily interested in passing path info to `Import` and `Export`.

Comment: What kind of content do you want to drag and drop? It works for Images. I am not exactly sure what action Mathematica should take when you drag and drop an arbitrary file. Do you just want the file's name to appear as a string?

Comment: That's an interesting question.  On Windows 7 that drag yields a list of file names within the folder.  Is that what you get also?

Comment: The file's path. Editing post to refer to Import/Export

Comment: Also you get strings for files that are text files. A text file containing {1,2,3,4} yields "{1,2,3,4}". Some drag and drop functionality is already implemented. It would be probably wise to avoid actually overloading it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Mac OS 10.7 just holding down the Option key while you drag works.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Is that documented?

Comment: Yes check out 'howto/InsertAFilePath'

Comment: On Windows one should hold down the `Ctrl`+`Shift` keys when releasing the mouse button. The cursor will change to indicate that a path will be inserted when you release the mouse button. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/InsertAFilePath.html